# how to input a string to textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible that the last `String` from a `list` can be input automatically to a `TextField`?

The list is empty for first few seconds and it is changing. It is also initialize after build context.

If yes please provide a code because I am new to flutter.

I know how to change the text from a textfield by using `TextEditingController`.

`final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();`

`TextField(controller: _controller)`

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    const newText = 'Hello World';
    final updatedText = _controller.text + newText;
    _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
      text: updatedText,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: updatedText.length),
    );
  },
)
```

but it has a button, how can I automate this?

Comment: Please, provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying.

Comment: I put some codes to clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by `TextEditingController`... Let's have a code example where you have a List of String.... e.g

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late TextEditingController _textEditingController;
  final List<String> _exampleList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _exampleList.add("apple");
            _textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: _exampleList.last);
          });
        }
      },
    );

    _textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: "Loading ...");

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextFormField(
            enabled: _exampleList.isNotEmpty,
            controller: _textEditingController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the result... this is just a simple explanation of how you can show last item of list in textfield

[image]

Comment: is it possible if the list is initialize after buildcontext and empty for few seconds?

Comment: You can create another async method with `Future.delay()` and call inside `initState`

Comment: yes you can use an async method and call in the initState so when your list updates it automatically assign your controller a value. Also other method you can use is adding listener to your controller both can be implemented

Comment: I have updated the code you can modify by yourself....You can show message as loading whatever you want. also you can disable the textfield by enable option till your list is empty (for better user experience)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and example. One last thing, I want to put `onChanged` on the `TextFormField` but it cant detect the text. The text will be detected when I click the `TextFormField` then onscreen keyboard will pop-out then type something

Comment: I read that `onChanged` doesn't run when the TextField's text is changed programmatically, via the TextField's controller. `TextEditingController.addListener` must be use but how can I implement that on this?

Comment: no no onchange simply track the changes during editing in textfield. I have updated the code you can see which updates the state on list update

Comment: my goal is to update a `ValueNotifier` with the `TextField`

Comment: then you can use onChange and in that you can assign _temp.value = stringValue; and you can listen that value using ValueListenableBuilder